# Meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere , generalization of a result

Tags: solution-verification, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions, riemann-sphere

I had an exercise that goes like this that i was able to solve but was wondering if it was true for more Riemann surfaces , hopefully something not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$.

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ such that their set of poles and zeroes are disjoint , then $\prod_{p\in \mathbb{C}_{\infty}}f(p)^{ord_p(g)}= \pm \prod_{p \in \mathbb{C}_{\infty}} g(p)^{ord_P(f)}$.

I have come up with a way to do this, that uses the fact that if $f$ is a meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere then if $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ denotes its set of poles and zeroes and $e_i =ord_{\lambda_i}(f)$, then $f=a\prod_{i=1}^{n}(z-\lambda_i)^{e_i}$, for some constant $a$ and then we just do the substituitions in each side and get the result we want. My quesiton is if there is an alternative way to do this, something a little more abstract, if there are other Riemann surfaces where this result is true and why ?

I have tried to see if this was even true for $\mathbb{P}^1$ because they are isomorphic but i still havent been able to do it, in fact i think its easy to construct a counterexample, wich is odd because the surfaces are isomorphic, does anyone know if this is true or not and give some insight on why ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a complex torus $\Bbb{C/(Z+\tau Z})$ we'll replace $z-a$ by $\theta(z-a;\tau)$ we still have that every non-zero meromorphic functions is of the form $r\frac{\prod_{j=1}^n\theta(z-a_j;\tau)}{\prod_{j=1}^n\theta(z-b_j;\tau)}$. And since $\theta(z ;\tau)$ is even  in $z$ the same formula holds.

Comment: Im not quite sure how we are going to relate $\theta^{x_i}(a_i)$ with $\theta^{a_i}(x_i)$ to give us the result we want, but thanks for the info !

Comment: No the idea is that evaluating $z-a$ at $b$ gives $b-a$, evaluating $z-b$ at $a$ gives $a-b$. It works the same way for $\theta(z-a)$

Comment: Yeah i dont what the definition of $\theta(z-a_i;\gamma)$ is for me the functions are $\theta^{x_i}(a_i)$